# Spring MVC, Ajax, Spanish Translation for real time messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am building a Spring MVC app. In one of the jsps, I have a jquery/ajax call to check if the username is available or not. The function works fine.

But I need to be able to translate the text that I return from the backend to Spanish. For all other texts in jsp like labels and so on, I can just use  code tag, but for this I am not sure how to handle this.

My jquery function & jsp snippet:

```
function unCheck() {
     var val = $('#userName').val();

     $.ajax({
       url : '*********',
       method : 'get',
       ContentType : 'json',
       data : {
           userName : val
       },
        success : function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
       },
       error : function() {
           window.location.replace("errorPage");
          }

     });

}
```

JSP:

```
<form:label path="userName">
    <span class="formLabel">
         <spring:message code="label.userName" /></span>
</form:label>
<form:input id="userName" path="userName" onchange="unCheck();" />
<form:errors path="userName"/>
<div id='result'></div> ---- This is where I display if username is available or taken already
```

How do I display the div id='result' in Spanish or English as needed(as all others)? Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Spring, in your application's backend. Here is a very simple tutorial explaining how to do it:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: Thanks Roman, but I have all the translation working expect the one where I am using Ajax to do the username check. Since this text comes directly to JQuery via Ajax, I am not sure how to handle/translate the text accordingly. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You want to make the translate in your front-end and not in the backend?

Comment: I am not sure how I would be able to make that translation in the backend, unless I get that locale information in my controller. So my assumption is if I translate in the backend, I would not be using the Spring translation mechanism(I might be wrong though). But if there is not other way, then I have to try doing that(translate into Spanish, then set the value in the response to be displayed in JSP). Thanks.

Comment: If you translate all your texts in your backend you can use the spring locale support to do it. It's very simple and there is an example in the link I gave it to you. Obviously you can make a translation in your front end if you want. In both ways, you need a way to know if you have to show a message in English or Spanish, Do you have a way to identify the language that you have to show?

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure I understand. As of now, when the page loads, I have an option(lang=es or lang=en and en being default). Then I have 2 property files having "label.userName" property with its appropriate value. So Spring(I have LocaleChangeInterceptor configured in my xml) would automatically detect and display the text accordingly. But for this specific scenario, I am not sure how to handle that, since the response value is in Ajax. " $('#result').html(response)" has the response and I need to display that in Spanish or English as all other values in the page. Continued-------------

Comment: Continuation:::: I am open to see if there is any other way to implement this. I tried to see if I can get the response assigned to a variable, but it did not work too. Thanks again.

Comment: Your variable "response" is the response of your ajax invocation to your spring controller. So, spring will determinate what text response depending on what's the "lang" value.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure it would work(I might be wrong though). Do you mind sending me a code snippet(the mykong would not work in my situation), may be with the example I posted? I can understand if you don't want to. Again thanks for all the help.